# Testing Core Data

Tags: core-data

I want to set up a mock for my Core data manager.

I'm doing this the old way for the core data stack, but want to do it for the exercise.

In the main Core Data Manager I set up with

```
var objectContext: NSManagedObjectContext! = nil
    var entity: NSEntityDescription! = nil
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
    objectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: Constants.entityName, in: objectContext)!
```

Now obviously I can't use UIApplication's persistent container in my mock.

So I tried to use the following:

```
objectContext =  NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
let entityOne = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: Constants.entityName, into: objectContext)
```

However I get the error "NSInvalidArgumentException", "+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSPersistentStoreCoordinator for searching for entity name 'TaskEntity'"

So how can I set a new objectContext for my mock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to create a full Core Data stack but let the persistent store reside in memory only. This way you don't have to deal with some app delegate dependency. Set context to nil and remove the store from the coordinator afterwards in `tearDown()`

```
class TestExample: XCTestCase {
    var storeCordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator!
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!
    var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel!
    var store: NSPersistentStore!

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()

        managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModel(from: nil)
        storeCordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: managedObjectModel)

        do {
            store = try storeCordinator.addPersistentStore(
                ofType: NSInMemoryStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: nil, options: nil)
        } catch {
            XCTFail("Failed to create a persistent store, \(error)")
        }
        managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = storeCordinator
    }
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but how do you do the tearDown() step, I'm struggling to remove the store from the coordinator.

Comment: There is a [remove](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentstorecoordinator/1468907-remove) method for that